# Customizing Django GenericRelation content_type values in Admin add/change view

Tags: django

My models are using `GenericForeignKey` and `GenericRelations`. For simplification my models structure is following:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     model_labels = models.GenericRelation('ModelLabel', related_query_name='%(class)s')
     model_types = models.GenericRelation('ModelType'), related_query_name='%(class)s')

     class Meta:
          abstract = True

class ModelA(BaseModel):
     fieldA = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class ModelB(BaseModel):
     fieldB = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class ModelLabel(models.Model);
     label = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
     content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
     model_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class ModelType(models.Model):
     type = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
     content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
     model_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Unrelated(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_lenght = 50)
```

The problem I am facing is in admin view for `ModelLabel` and `ModelType`. Right now, out-of-the-box I am getting 3 fields: `Label` or `Type`, `Content type` and `Object id`. Yes, this is correct according to the model.

But in `Content type` I am getting not only `ModelA` and `ModelB` as an options. I'm also getting `Unrelated` and most of the individual fields of different models. According to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#overview):

> Instances of ContentType represent and store information about the
>   models installed in your project, and new instances of ContentType are
>   automatically created whenever new models are installed.

According to this `Unrelated` can appear in the values, but models' fields shouldn't. So why they appear?

However, this is not the main problem I am struggling with. I'd like to narrow the list of options to choose from in `Content type` **just to** `ModelA` and `ModelB`. From what I gathered since this is `ForeignKey` under the hood I should be able to go with [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), but I would need to make it use some hardcoded `QuerySet` but I cannot find how to make it e.g. from dictionary. Similar goes with `Object id`, where I'd like to be able to select what value I want to use based on available numbers.

So far I realized that most likely I need to extend `admin.ModelAdmin` view and most likely also create custom form (extend `forms.ModelForm`). This is also theory because so far I couldn't figure a way to get mentioned custom `QuerySet` or `Object id`. Also there is some drawback of this approach, because if I'll choose to go with this, I'll need to have custom form for every model (`ModelLabel`, `ModelType`) - is this really necessary?

I know of a way to add GenericInlineModelAdmin class, but this view allows to add object of type `ModelLabel` together with `ModelB`. This doesn't cover case where object of type `ModelB` already exists.

To summarize what are main goals I want to achieve:

1. Fix Admin view to create `ModelLabel` and `ModelType`
2. Narrow list of options for `Content type` field to `ModelA` and `ModelB`
3. Allow user to choose only existing IDs for `Object id` field